# Highcharts - is it possible to maintain grouping in scatter chart

Tags: highcharts, axis

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/) I've made the following changes,

```
 chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        inverted:true
    },
```

Is it possible to maintain different rows for different groups(here stacks)?

I'm doing something in the lines of plan vs actual. And would want plan in one line and actual in other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pointPlacement`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointPlacement). For example: http://jsfiddle.net/joy0zs2n/

```
series: [{
  name: 'Current',
  data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
  pointPlacement: -0.25
}, {
  name: 'Plan',
  data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
  pointPlacement: 0.25
}]
```